# How to install PHP extension 'pcntl' on my Mac OSX without brew

Tags: php, macos, pcntl

So, I'm trying to install the pcntl extension on my MacBook Pro (High Sierra 10.13.4).

I tried following the guides that I can find online, but they are all outdated, since Homebrew decided to move all php packages to their core, and delete some of them in the process. 
(https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php, WTF Homebrew?!)
The pcntl php extension is one of those packages.

This was done the end of March, so very recently. Nobody asked this question since then.

Is there any other way to install the pcntl extension on a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They didn't drop the extension they decided on compiling it with php by default.

While according to this [brew formular](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/php@7.1.rb#L101) it should be available in `php71` it only is available starting with `php72`

Comment: Thank you for replying :) It's just too bad that our projects require php 5.6, not 7. So I guess there is no solution for 5.6 users then?